# cURL not working with localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I am using CentOS 6.5, when I am giving the following command, curl is working fine and it returns me a proper output:
curl --data "atoken=0564af8vabe91f2d1a82fb1j375345733e35b707" http://www.mywebsite.com/something.json

However, I need the same thing on my local machine. In this case, it's not working:

curl --data "atoken=0564af8vabe91f2d1a82fb1j375345733e35b707" http://localhost/something.json

It gives errors and the output like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
    body {...
```

Please help.
Also, how can I get the atoken for localhost?

Comment: What error does the page report?

Comment: It displays the long code of the website and nothing else:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
      color: #333;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    body, p, ol, ul, td {
      font-family: helvetica, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:   13px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }

    pre {
      font-size: 11px;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
    }

    pre.box {
      border: 1px solid #EEE;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0px;
      width: 958px;
    }..

Comment: It's an html error page for rails. Save it to a file and open it in your web browser.

Comment: When I open localhost in web browser, it opens up the mywebsite.com, but, what I want is that curl should return a json hash for localhost, just like it is returning for mywebsite.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl is working... what's not working is the JSON service.  It's expecting data that it's not getting, or it's not configured correctly on localhost.

Comment: Its returning a json hash for: curl --data "atoken=0564af8cabe91f2d1a89fb18375345793e35s707" http://www.mywebsite.com/coords.json

{"919876556789":[{"lat":62.850307,"lng":90.916853,"tim":"2015-02-26T02:48:27.406Z"},{"lat":26.850307,"lng":80.916853,"tim":"2015-02-17T16:05:57.781Z"}]}

But, it's not working for:

curl --data "atoken=0564af8cabe91f2d1a89fb18375345793e35s707" http://localhost/coords.json

Comment: if you run the curl tests on the same machine, and one test works and the other doesn't, it rules out Curl being the problem.  The problem would be the service running on localhost/coords.json.

Comment: You'll need to find the exact exception that is being thrown.  Try looking through the server logs for the exception that is thrown, or turn on logging if possible.  The localhost website is not installed correctly, it looks like.

Comment: My first guess would be to look at the database connections... they will be different between live and localhost.  Or check folder paths.  Anything that is not the same between live and localhost may need to change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, database connections and other things seem to be fine. I guess the two tokens for mywebsite.com and localhost would be different from each other. Could you please tell me how can I check what is the token on localhost?

Comment: I don't know on that... that would be specific to the application code.  Though I might look at the database for this first, and possibly any global config files.  If you can, get a dump of the live database and search it for the string, and search the code as well.

Comment: Though, without seeing the details of the exception, it's hard to know that the atoken is the problem.  It could be some other problem also...